HTML audio element is disabled even though src is correct
I have an HTML audio element with src pointing to a valid URL, but the audio element is greyed out and disabled. Right next to the audio element, I have a link that goes to directly the src URL, which correctly points to the mp3 file on S3.
I can't figure out why the audio player is in a disabled state. It's implemented in Svelte code below. Happening in Chrome and Safari browsers.
How can I remove the disabled state from this audio player?
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { slide } from 'svelte/transition';
    import { BACKEND_URL } from '$lib/constants';
    import { isRtlLanguage } from '$lib/utils';
    import Ping from '$lib/components/loading/Ping.svelte';

    export let text = 'hello';
    export let language = 'English';

    let isLoading = true;
    let audioUrl;

    onMount(async () => {
        await handleSubmit();
    });

    async function handleSubmit() {
        isLoading = true;
        audioUrl = null;
        const response = await fetch(BACKEND_URL + 'text-to-speech', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ text, language })
        });
        const r = await response.json();
        audioUrl = r.outputUri;
        isLoading = false;
    }
</script>

<div in:slide out:slide class="flex {isRtlLanguage(language) ? 'justify-end' : ''}">
    {#if isLoading}
        <div class="flex space-x-3">
            <div class="pt-1">
                <Ping />
            </div>
            <div class="text-sm text-gray">Generating voice response...</div>
        </div>
    {:else if audioUrl}
        <div class="flex space-x-4">
            <div class="rounded-full border border-lightgray">
                <audio controls>
                    <source src={audioUrl} type="audio/mp3">
                </audio>
            </div>
            <div class="pt-4">
                <a href={audioUrl} target="_blank" class="hovertext">
                    <i class="bi bi-box-arrow-right"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/if}
</div>




Your HTML is invalid. The <i> tag needs a closing </i>. Also, the <source> tag does not use or need a closing slash.

@Rob: This generally does not matter in Svelte. It correctly closes elements like i that require the closing tag. The redundant / in source is also removed. (Svelte 5 will generate a warning for things like <i />.)

Would an input in the same position as the audio also be disabled? Please provide a full but minimal reproduction - there is no issue in the given code.

I added the full code. The closing slashes in <i> and <source> don't have any effect.

Have you in S3 fixed permissions, so the file is public and anyone is allowed to retrieve it?

Yes, the file is public in S3. If I click the link that goes directly to S3, it redirects there

The problem is fixed if I add a small delay between when the S3 audio file URL is generated and when I mount the audio player: setTimeout(() => {isLoading = false}, 2000);.
This gives enough time for the audio URL to become accessible by the audio player.
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { slide } from 'svelte/transition';
    import { BACKEND_URL } from '$lib/constants';
    import { isRtlLanguage } from '$lib/utils';
    import Ping from '$lib/components/loading/Ping.svelte';

    export let text = 'hello';
    export let language = 'English';

    let isLoading = true;
    let audioUrl;

    onMount(() => {
        handleSubmit();
    });

    async function handleSubmit() {
        isLoading = true;
        const response = await fetch(BACKEND_URL + 'text-to-speech', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ text, language })
        });
        const r = await response.json();
        audioUrl = r.outputUri;

        // give short delay until audio is ready.
        // this is to remedy a bug with the
        // S3 source on the audio player.
        setTimeout(() => {
            isLoading = false;
        }, 2000);
    }
</script>

<div in:slide out:slide class="flex {isRtlLanguage(language) ? 'justify-end' : ''}">
    {#if isLoading}
        <div class="flex space-x-3">
            <div class="pt-1">
                <Ping />
            </div>
            <div class="text-sm text-gray">Generating voice response...</div>
        </div>
    {:else}
        <div class="rounded-full border border-lightgray">
            <audio controls>
                <source src={audioUrl} type="audio/mp3" />
            </audio>
        </div>
    {/if}
</div>

